# Keras Custom Layer ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created a custom Keras Layer. The model compiles fine, but gives me the following error while training:

> ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure
>   that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are
>   differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round,
>   K.eval.

Is there any implementation error in my custom layer?

```
class SpatialLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(SpatialLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bias = None
        self.built = True
        self.kernelA = self.add_weight(name='kernelA', shape=(input_shape[1]-2, self.output_dim), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]-2, input_shape[1]-2, self.output_dim)


    def call(self, inputs):
        x_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        top_values, top_indices = tf.nn.top_k(tf.reshape(inputs, (-1,)), 10, sorted=True,)
        top_indices = tf.stack(((top_indices // x_shape[1]), (top_indices % x_shape[1])), -1)
        top_indices = tf.cast(top_indices, dtype=tf.float32)
        t1 = tf.reshape(top_indices, (1,10,2))
        t2 = tf.reshape(top_indices, (10,1,2))
        result = tf.norm(t1-t2, ord='euclidean', axis=2)
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10, 10, 1])
        tensor_zeros = tf.zeros_like(x)
        matrix = tensor_zeros + result
        return K.dot(matrix, self.kernelA)


    model = applications.VGG16(weights = "imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))
    model.layers.pop()
    new_custom_layers = model.layers[-1].output
    model.layers[-1].trainable = False

    new_custom_layers = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3))(new_custom_layers)
    new_custom_layers = SpatialLayer(output_dim=1)(new_custom_layers)
    new_custom_layers = Flatten()(new_custom_layers)
    new_custom_layers = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(new_custom_layers)
    new_custom_layers = Dropout(0.5)(new_custom_layers)
    new_custom_layers = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(new_custom_layers)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Explanation**

The input to my custom Keras Layer is a tensor (?, 12,12,1) that represents a feature map from a given image. 
For example:

```
[[147.00  20.14 ... 0 34.2  0   ]
 [ 12.00  10.14 ... 0 45.2  0   ]
 ...
 [100.00  60.14 ... 0 34.2  99.1]
 [ 90.00  65.14 ... 0 12.2  00.1]]
```

I want to get the coordinates of the top 10 values from this tensor, 
for example: (0,0), (10,0) ...., (10,11), i.e., 10 coordinates.

Finally, I want to calculate a distance matrix between the coordinates. I am using euclidean distance.
For example:

```
       coord1 coord2 ... coord9 cood10
coord1   0     12.3       13.1   2.3
coord2  1.3      0        3.2    9.1
  .
  .
  .
coord9  4.2     5.2        0     4.2
coor10  1.1     5.6       9.1     0
```

This matrix (?, 10,10,1) will be the layer output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot backpropagate through functions that are not differentiable. 
And your function is not differentiable.

You discarded the values `top_values` and kept only integer constants `top_indices`.

The only way to use this layer in a model is if everything before it is not trainable. (Or if you find another way of calculating what you want in a differentiable way - this means: operations that must involve the input values)

Comment: Daniel, I need to calculate a distance matrix between the top 10 values from input tensor. This matrix will be the layer output. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182398/creating-a-distance-matrix-in-tensorflow/60182819?noredirect=1#comment106480984_60182819) is an example of a  distance matrix in another post of mine. Thanks!

Comment: Are they coordinate pairs? How do you want to sort pairs?

Comment: I edited the post with an explanation about what I intend to do in the custom layer. I aim to classify images. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's easy to do what you want.... you could on the other hand try to work directly with coordinates instead of with feature maps. In this case, you'd go well with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988185/how-to-produce-a-variable-size-distance-matrix-in-keras/59989355#59989355

Comment: And for some reason, I think this one is closely related to your case... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082775/how-to-implement-a-gaussian-renderer-with-mean-and-variance-values-as-input-in-a/60102314#60102314

Is this a Kaggle competition? :p

Comment: It's a master's degree.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using Lambda Layer.
Even with a simple code.

`from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

def my_function(inputs):
 return K.zeros_like(inputs)

new_custom_layers = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='Teste')(new_custom_layers)
new_custom_layers = Lambda(my_function)(new_custom_layers) 
new_custom_layers = Flatten()(new_custom_layers)`

Comment: This is expected. Zeros are not differentiable. They're integer constants, exactly like the indices.